# Free-of-charge solution to populate XML with data from misc sources

Tags: xml

I have to generate XML documents based on several data sources (database, rest services). For example list of persons from several corporate systems **persons.xml**:

```
<persons>
  <person>
    <name></name>
    <birthdate></birthdate>
     ...
  </person>
   ...
</persons>
```

I don't want to code much (please, no loops, conditions and streams in any programming language) or to use commercial products fo that.
I am agree to collect all external data into another XML, for instance:
**data.xml**

```
<data>
  <source name="database"> 
    <persons>...</persons>   
  </source>
  <source name="restservice1">
    <persons>...</persons>   
  </source>
  <source name="restservice2">
    <persons>...</persons>   
  </source>
</data>
```

I want to have template-file that describes how to form XML document (persons.xml) based on data file (data.xml) - what technology/product is the most flexible for that?

I have read that XSLT is outdated today and I had so much pain in the past with XSLT that I'd like to put my hands on anything other then XSLT.

Any other approach how to present data from misc sources is also acceptable

Answer (score 1):

XSLT is not outdated, in fact it has a very active community.

Avoiding loops will restrict to reach your aim. Even if you do not directly add the programming syntax of loops, they are often called in the background.

I agree that XSLT as programming language is a bit steep coming from other languages. Best is to have a mindset of thinking about the source file as a db (even though its not) but it helps when construction template queries.

It is worth the effort of learning XSLT. You will gain speed if you have some patience. Choosing a simpler language or tool will most probably cause problems for you later on in your template journey.

Below you find a portion of XSLT 3.0 that could fulfill your need, but it might not be exactly as you requested because you have left out some information, such as what should be presented in the XML and how the data should be grouped.Since not running loops the code is really hardcoded and will not be that much of use when and if you need to expand the XML source data file.

**data.xml**

```
<persons
  xmlns:persons="http://www.example.com/1"
  >
  <person>
    <name>Frank</name>
    <birthdate>21st of May 2021</birthdate>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>Anita</name>
    <birthdate>5st of May 2021</birthdate>
  </person>
</persons>
```

**xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:transform version="3.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.example.com/0"
  xmlns:persons="http://www.example.com/1"
  xmlns:males="http://www.example.com/2"
  xmlns:females="http://www.example.com/3"
>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">

    <data>

      <source name="database">

        <males:persons>
          <xsl:value-of select="persons/person[1]"/>
        </males:persons>
        <females:persons>
          <xsl:value-of select="persons/person[2]"/>
        </females:persons>

      </source>

    </data>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data xmlns="http://www.example.com/0"
      xmlns:females="http://www.example.com/3"
      xmlns:males="http://www.example.com/2"
      xmlns:persons="http://www.example.com/1">
   <source name="database">
      <males:persons>
    Frank
    21st of May 2021
  </males:persons>
      <females:persons>
    Anita
    5st of May 2021
  </females:persons>
   </source>
</data>
```